# ROracle package on M1 Mac - what version combinations will work?

Tags: r, oracle19c, roracle

I'm running R 4.2.1 (ARM) installed via Home-brew on a M1 PowerBook with x86 Oracle's instant client 19.8 + SDK (Oracle only has legacy processor architectures available as of October 2022) that fuels my `isql` command line access to an Oracle DB.

I wish to have a solution to retrieve query results from that remote Oracle DB in R, like I can in Python with `oracledb`. I spent a day trying to find a ODBC solution, but it seems not to be an option as [connectors for oracle are unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72059573/cant-use-oracle-obdc-driver-in-r-in-mac-m1-architecture) or [cost money](https://blog.devart.com/odbc-drivers-with-support-for-apple-m1.html) wish is not an alternative in this project. Maybe Oracle just hates ARM. :(

My attempts to install the "ROracle" package exits with `installation of package ‘ROracle’ had non-zero exit status`. ROracle seems to be from 2016, and when I try to compile a package it tells me that `...ROracle/’ is not available for this version of R`.

No installation manuals speaks decently about the combinations of package, sdk, and R versions needed to run ROracle on modern Macs. Do you think "not available for this version of R" refers to my ARM-version or the 4.2.1 version?

If I'd know of a working combinations of versions of R, Oracle Instant Client and SDK, I would save a lot of time, so please let me know any of your working configs for ROracle on M1 Macs if this is at all possible.

I get a bit further using `remotes::install_local(type='source')` but it fails too, like this:

```
Skipping 1 packages not available: DBI
Running `R CMD build`...
* checking for file ‘/private/var/folders/qf/jbng9jq14n34gdrpmjfhksmm0000gn/T/RtmpPIsi0k/file1253742cf18be/ROracle_Mac/DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
* preparing ‘ROracle’:
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* cleaning src
* running ‘cleanup’
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* building ‘ROracle_1.3-1.tar.gz’
* installing *source* package ‘ROracle’ ...
** using staged installation
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/Users/josef/instantclient_19_8/sdk/include  -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c rodbi.c -o rodbi.o
rodbi.c:2432:53: warning: format specifies type 'long long' but the argument has type 'sb8' (aka 'long') [-Wformat]
        sprintf(err_buf, RODBI_ERR_BIND_VAL_TOOBIG, bndsz);
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/secure/_stdio.h:47:56: note: expanded from macro 'sprintf'
  __builtin___sprintf_chk (str, 0, __darwin_obsz(str), __VA_ARGS__)

 etc.
```

Comment: I see 'arm64' in the compile line. I think you need to be create x86 binaries.   Maybe try exploring how to force an x64 build?  Perhaps use `export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"` somewhere in the tool chain?  I know this environment variable was needed for some Python builds even when building on Mac Intel.  Possibly also look at running the shell in x86 mode, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73729108/i-have-issue-in-nodejs-connect-to-database-oracle-in-macbook-m1-max-help-me.